# How do I invite an iTunes Connect user to test an app without an email?

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

My tester's Apple Id isn't a valid email. He uses an alias. But iTunes Connect is trying to send invites to their alias.

Can I invite them another way?

Comment: The alias still need to be a valid email to approve them though right?

Comment: Yes, it sent the approval email there, but not the tester email!

Comment: So I don't understand how they approved the alias with apple but not able to receive the invite email

Comment: If the alias is recognised by Apple, then it should just appear in the TestFlight app on their phone. e.g. if I sign into TestFlight on my phone then I can approve new apps there and don't need to see the email

Comment: Yes, that could be it. They approved the alias and then I presume the alias was replaced by the official ID.

Comment: No, test flight asks for an invitation code.

Comment: ... which it sends to the official Apple Id email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The tester created a new Apple account.

Comment: @kometen How's that?

Comment: I'll delete my comments since they don't provide any information. :-)

Answer (score 1):

See this this message from within the Settings of the TestFlight app.

> You can accept invites with your current Apple ID, even if the invite email and Apple ID don't match. To use another Apple ID, go to Settings > iTunes & App Store.

So my take from that is send the invite to an email address that they can receive and just have them accept it on their device.

[image: TestFlight]

Comment: Send which invite though? How would I get an invite?

Comment: My redeem code didn't work with their Apple account.

Comment: Can you not create an `@icloud.com` email to receive the email at? Like `dave.work@icloud.com`

Comment: I've asked the tester to change their Apple Id. They've got a working email alias and a defunct email for their Apple Id.

Comment: Creating a brand new Apple Id means they'd have to switch accounts - which would be very inconvenient.

Comment: I would say the best solution is that they are able to receive emails for their Apple ID, what if their account is compromised and they did to receive a recovery email or something of the like.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. You can delete emails, including the one marked as "Apple Id" apparently, in the phone's settings. I've suggested that they do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could put them into a separate Test group  in TestFlight and then invite them that way.

They won't be considered as a Developer, but the invite should go out.

Comment: Isn't that for external testing only?

Comment: Well, "external" is sort of an odd word (I know, Apple uses it...) - what it means is "not an Apple developer" - i.e., "external" to Apple.  It works with any email (at least, all I have tried)....  Should be worth a try for your situation where Apple is not recognizing the person.

Comment: External testers will only have access to the app if Apple has reviewed the app. I haven't got that far.

Comment: I guess I never thought about anything like that as I don't have other testers that are "internal" - so, as soon as the app was ready to test by anyone else (very 'raw' stuff where I needed feedback on views, etc.), I put it out to 'external' people.  The Apple review process seems to care more about permission, background data and certain verbiage than 'function' of the app (my experience on two apps so far that went out to 'external' testers before there was even a login page), so putting it out for review (to get 'external' testers) really isn't that big a deal.